# Laravel 5.4 : The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths

Tags: php, laravel, configuration

It is Laravel 5.4 setup of my web app. 
one thing is happening repeatedly on page load. and because of that, I am not able to get data on my page.

**Runtime exception: The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.**

Got this error repeatedly

I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: So it's happening sometimes but not all the time?

Comment: yes, not all the time

Comment: I'm facing this same error in my laravel5.3 project with php7.4

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your app config has key and cipher set. Also make sure your .env file does not have an empty APP_KEY entry. Finally run:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to set APP_Key in **.env** file and then run following command in the terminal of your application root.

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Answer (score 2):

i was getting the same error 
run this command 
`php artisan key:generate`
and then this command
`php artisan config:clear`

Answer (score 0):

i was getting the same error.

run this command.

```
php artisan key:generate
```

updated the app key in .env

work for me

you can take help from [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xxVQMyDToE)